# SELECT statements not returning any rows due to data with white space. Use TRIM() to fix

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I use the below query.

```
SELECT a1.unit_name, a1.attack_name, att.unit_name, att.attack_name
FROM Army_1 a1, Attacks att
```

I get this data.

```
Arkanaut Company, Aethermatic Volley Gun, Arkanaut Company, Privateer Pistol

Arkanaut Company, Aethermatic Volley Gun, Arkanaut Company, Aethermatic Volley Gun
```

But using a WHERE clause with a1.unit_name = att.unit_name. I get no rows.
Is there something obvious I am missing?

EDIT:

Table inserts

```
CREATE TABLE Army_1 (
    ID          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Unit_Name   VARCHAR,
    Attack_Name VARCHAR,
    Quantity    INT
);

CREATE TABLE Attacks (
    Unit_Name           REFERENCES Models (Unit_Name),
    Attack_Name VARCHAR,
    Attack_Type VARCHAR,
    Attacks     INTEGER,
    To_Hit      INTEGER,
    To_Wound    INTEGER,
    Rend        INTEGER,
    Damage      INTEGER
);
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want to do a `join`.

Comment: Hi CollinD, that still returns 0 rows?

Comment: Sounds like spaces or non compatible character encodings.

Comment: update your question and add  a table schema .. proper data  sample and the expected  result please

Comment: I have added table schemas.

Comment: If I had to guess, you have non-display data in your one of the name fields `A1.unit_name` or `att.unit_name`  check the length of both to see if the lenghts match.  try Trim() to eliminate spaces leading or trailing.  do some have a carriage return or line feed?

Comment: Thanks xQbert, TRIM() has solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to xQbert, I needed to use TRIM() on my WHERE clause. This solved the problem.

Comment: 15+ years of (Extract Transform and Load) data quality is always suspect when it looks like it should match :P

Comment: Sanitize the data or join on system managed keys instead of user defined input.

Comment: Thanks xQbert, I am now redesigning the user defined input. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might want to do a JOIN.

Try this:

```
SELECT a1.unit_name, a1.attack_name, att.unit_name, att.attack_name
FROM Army_1 a1
INNER JOIN Attacks att ON a1.unit_name = att.unit_name
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks but still returning 0 rows. Are you assuming any pk or fk's? I really can't get my head around this 1.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are some overlapping unit names in both the tables?

Comment: Yes Arkanaut Company is 1 which I put in the question